# Highcharts has incorrect chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Tell me why my example does not work properly?

`url: http://jsfiddle.net/LtkX2/`

Thanks!

P.S. 
The problem is solved. Time difference was very small and without closer it seemed that graph is wrong. Thank you for your attention. =)

Comment: a) Post your code here as well. b) What exactly does not work? What is the expected result?

Comment: ??? `Tell me why my example does not work properly?` How can we tell you what isn't working correctly when you haven't even defined what `working correctly` is?

Comment: When viewing the data array is visible problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you expect, that tooltip should be displayed in on each point. All series except scatter have to be sorted and only one point for a one x-value. So you can use scatter series with defined lineWidth.

```
series: [{
            type:'scatter',
            lineWidth:2,
            data: Data
        }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LtkX2/1/

Comment: The problem with drawing the line. If you see the values ​​in the array, we can see that the first value should be 32. If you use the axis type datetime and the value of UTC, and the graph is incorrect. If the data transfer in the format "string", then all right.

Comment: The schedule should look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LtkX2/2/

Comment: The problem is solved. Time difference was very small and without closer it seemed that graph is wrong. Thank you for your attention.